# Determining source location of label method in Rails when using helper method inside Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, rails-console

I understand that there are two `label` methods (`ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper#label` and `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder#label`) available in Rails. Which `#label` method is being called when the following is being typed in the `rails console`:

```rb
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.7.2)
2.6.0 :001 > helper.label(:post, :title, "A short title", class: "title_label")
 => "<label class=\"title_label\" for=\"post_title\">A short title</label>"
```

I've gone into `gems/actionview-5.0.7.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb` and commented out both `label` methods like so:

```rb
#      def label(object_name, method, content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)
#        Tags::Label.new(object_name, method, self, content_or_options, options).render(&block)
#      end
.
.
.
#      def label(method, text = nil, options = {}, &block)
#        @template.label(@object_name, method, text, objectify_options(options), &block)
#      end
```

Yet it's still executing the `label` method in the Rails console, how can I determine the source location of this method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the first one. The second needs a `FormBuilder` object (the `f.` part) to work.

Did you reload the console after commenting out those methods?

I you are using [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/) you can use `show-method`:

```rb
pry(main)> show-method helper.label

From: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@gemset/gems/actionview-5.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb @ line 1114:
Owner: ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 3

def label(object_name, method, content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)
  Tags::Label.new(object_name, method, self, content_or_options, options).render(&block)
end
```

Comment: Yes i commend out the methods and reloaded the console. Which still returned `"<label class=\"title_label\" for=\"post_title\">A short title</label>"` which I thought was strange.

Comment: I thought it would return something like undefined method since it's been commented out?

Comment: It should, indeed: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'label' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000008c0d688>`. Do you have different gemsets on your system? Are you using the Ruby version you think you are using?

Comment: Btw, on my system I had to exit console. `reload!` wasn't enough.

Comment: I did try exiting still didn't work on my system. Thanks for the help.